# geting async YouTube title from get-youtube-title npm library

Tags: javascript, yt

I need to get a title from YouTube video. How can I change a request from this library to be async? Actually this returns `undefined`

this is a vue.js app

```
async addNewVideoToLocalStorage() {
     let id = getIdFromURL(this.videosUrl[0].url);
     let title = await getYoutubeTitle(id, async (e, t) => await t);
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-youtube-title

Comment: You return nothing. Please add: return title;

Comment: You may find this useful https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-youtube-title-await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data: () => ({
  title: "",
})
```

```
async get_title() {
      var getYoutubeTitle = require('get-youtube-title');
      let id = 'QR1jRM4XTyc';
      await getYoutubeTitle(id, (e, t) => {
        return this.title = t
      })
      console.log(this.title);
}
```

async , await cannot work in getYoutubeTitle

try this way

Comment: Thank bro, :) Can you give me hint why I need to add this to `data` value ?

Comment: @pawelszewczyk Heyyyy bro, Good morning. 
I just wanna check the value in `<template></template>` like this 

`<v-btn @click="get_title()"> GET TITLE TEST </v-btn>
   <div> display value here : {{ title }} </div>`

bc you're in Vue environment rn the reason why I use the `data` value.